# How do i tell if a cron job on OpenShift is working or not?

Tags: cron, openshift, density-independent-pixel

I have an OpenShift DIY cartridge so, i need to do some work daily, i read this article :
[Run CRON job every 5 minutes on OpenShift (Red Hat Cloud)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071615/run-cron-job-every-5-minutes-on-openshift-red-hat-cloud)
and do it by making a file in :
~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/cron/minutely/awesome_job.sh 
with content which is :

```
  #!/bin/bash
    #chmod +x ~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/cron/minutely/awesome_job.sh 
    #minute=$(date '+%M')
    #if [ $minute == 12 ]; then
    minute=$(date +%M)
    if [[ $minute =~ [05]$ ]]; then
        date > ~/app-root/runtime/repo/www/sie.txt  

    fi
```

so how can i tell if it is working or not? ( or i need to run some app via rhc for running cron job in default DIY cartridge)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
date > ~/app-root/runtime/repo/www/sie.txt
```

to

```
echo date > ~/app-root/runtime/repo/www/sie.txt
```

so that the results of the "date" command will actually get pushed into that file